# Pathfinder Natural Weapon Damage by Size Inconsistency

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Source: https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Natural_Attacks

Take for example a bite attack. According to the table, a small bite does 1d4 damage, medium 1d6, large 1d8, huge 2d6, garg. 2d8, and col. 4d6. Presumably it'd continue 4d8, 8d6, etc.

However, if you look at the FAQ entry right below it, it says that as you increase the damage, the progression would be 1d4, 1d6, 1d8, 2d6, 3d6, 4d6, 6d6, 8d6, 12d6, etc.

So what is this supposed to mean? Does it mean for example that a gargantuan entity would do 2d8 damage with a bite attack, but a huge one enlarged to gargantuan would do 3d6?

This seems it might be a duplicate of [Is there an error in the universal monster rules for table:natural attacks by size?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/is-there-an-error-in-the-universal-monster-rules-for-tablenatural-attacks-by-si)
That question is 2 years old. Have we gotten any new information since then?
Also, the newer chart is listed as a FAQ instead of an errata, which implies that the old chart might not be a mistake?

Comment: Instead of opening a duplicate question, I believe the correct protocol would be to comment in (or, when you have enough Reputation, put a Bounty on) the other question. Commenting should be enough to draw some new attention to it.

Comment: @Ifusaso Thanks for the bounty on my original question, I believe its the first time Ive earned that

Answer (score 0):

No. There has not been any new information to answer and/or solve the original question.

To answer what you asked, you would follow what happens when you are the size and then apply the spell effects. You do not get to choose whichever is better, the new modified size, or the new modified damage. You must take the original size and then add the increased damage.