# SoP Destructive Blast Damage Dice Steps

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage, spheres-of-power

Related: [Pathfinder Damage Dice Steps](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/27512/23058)

Spheres of Power (SoP) is an alternative/expanded magic system for Pathfinder. The destruction sphere gives the caster access to an unlimited ray attack which can be expanded on in many ways by different talents.

There are many talents which change the damage the blast can deal, either by increasing or decreasing the size of the dice. Specifically there is a talent called [Greater Blast](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/destruction#toc14). Since this is applied without using a shape or type its good.

> #### Greater Blast
>
> The damage of your destructive blast increases by one die. You may take this talent an additional time at 5th caster level and every 5 caster levels thereafter; the effects stack.

At the bottom of the destruction sphere page under [wild magic](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/destruction#toc88) it lists

> Increase the effect’s damage die size by 1 step (1d4, 1d6, 1d8, 1d10, 1d12).

Since the base blast does 1d6, the first time it’s taken it increases to 1d8, and the second time to 1d10. Both sources agree to this point. It’s what happens after that’s not clear. Does it become 1d12 as suggested by the wild magic table which is not the specific source as wild magic is different from the blast? Or should I strictly follow the damage die progression chart and deal 2d6?

Comment: @Cyrad See [this FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/321) for why your comment was removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## Greater Blast does not increase damage die step.

The Greater Blast talent says "The damage of your destructive blast increases by **one die**." It does not say "one die step." The talent gives you an extra damage die. So if your blast does 3d6, then the talent increases the damage to 4d6.

## The text implies 1d12 is the maximum damage die.

The text "(1d4, 1d6, 1d8, 1d10, 1d12)" is repeated several times in the wild magic table, suggesting a range from 1d4 to 1d12 that *destructive blast* can deal.

## Damage die step after 1d12 is 2d8.

According to [Paizo's FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9t3f), a 1d12 counts as a 2d6 on the damage die step chart. The step after 2d6 is 2d8. If your GM interprets the text that your *destructive blast* can exceed the range implied by the wild magic rules, then the blast would deal 2d8 per damage die.

Comment: since the base blast is 1d6, at 20th CL and assuming all other upgrades have been selected, that would be 5 increases. So 1d6->1d8->1d10->1d12->???->???. Even the 1d4 would be able to progress past the 1d12.

Comment: Also, are not the wild magic rules further optional rules and not required in every game with SoP? Also, there are other die then those listed in that list. What about a d7 which is normally used for days of the week?

Comment: As my answer says, Greater Blast does **not** increase the damage die step. It increases the number of damage dice.

Your question specifically asked about wild magic rules. Other talents do not increase the damage die beyond a 1d12. Also, a d7 is not used for damage dice in Pathfinder.

Comment: The question only asked about those rules due to having had a large misunderstanding